# Is it possible to create a reflect.Type of an Interface with custom methods?

Tags: go

I want to define an interface's properties in `reflect.Type` for serialization/deserialization purposes. I've looked and there doesn't seem to be an `InterfaceOf([]*Methods)` function (analogous to [StructOf](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf)).

My ultimate goal is to serialize and deserialize a reflect.Type using protobufs. I need to be able to recreate a function using `FuncOf` where one of the parameters is an interface.

Say I have a function with the signature `func foo(x interface{bar()})`, I can do:

```
reflect.TypeOf(f)        // func(interface { main.t() })
// and
reflect.TypeOf(f).In(0)  // interface { main.t() }
```

but I can't build that description. I can get the empty interface type:

```
itf := reflect.TypeOf((*interface{})(nil)).Elem() // interface{}
// and
FuncOf([]reflect.Type{itf}, []reflect.Type{}, false)
```

I see [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4146) which suggests that what I'm looking to do isn't possible but I was hoping there is some work around for my use case.

https://play.golang.org/p/WGgFxporB_Q

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? There's likely a way to do it but not by this approach. An interface type defined at runtime has no use; the only use for interface types is as variable/parameter/field types, which you can't use it for if it's defined at runtime.

Comment: It seems when you dive this far down the reflect rabbit hole, interfaces are redundant as you can already get methods by name and call them dynamically.